# Changing one picture to another onclick in vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Assume that I have a normal picture box with a picture loaded, how can I change the picture within when the user clicks on it?

Example: Clipart of a book changing to clipart of an ocean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
Dim OldImage As Image

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    OldImage = PictureBox1.Image 'This will store the image before changing. Set this in Form1_Load() handler

    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\xyz.jpg") 'Method 1 : This will load the image in memory
    PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "C:\xyz.jpg" 'Method 2 : This will load the image from the filesystem and other apps won't be able to edit/delete the image
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Image 'Method 3 : This will also load the image in memory from a resource in your appc

    PictureBox1.Image = OldImage 'Set the image again to the old one
End Sub
```

Comment: Would there be any way to change the picture back using any of these methods though?

Answer (score 2):

Keep the images in a list and change the image of the PictureBox by specificying an index from the list:

Simple example with a `PictureBox`:

```
Public Class Form1
  Private _Images As New List(Of Image)
  Private _ImageIndex As Integer

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    For i As Integer = 1 To 3
      Dim bmp As New Bitmap(32, 32)
      Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        Select Case i
          Case 1 : g.Clear(Color.Blue)
          Case 2 : g.Clear(Color.Red)
          Case 3 : g.Clear(Color.Green)
        End Select
      End Using
      _Images.Add(bmp)
    Next

  End Sub

  Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    If _Images.Count > 0 Then
      PictureBox1.Image = _Images(_ImageIndex)
      _ImageIndex += 1
      If _ImageIndex > _Images.Count - 1 Then
        _ImageIndex = 0
      End If
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```